# On change loading image not working for multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".catclass").live("change", function(){
            var whichcat = $(this).attr('id')   
            var catid = $(this).val();        
            var url = 'ajaxcat.php'; 
            //$('#tblLoading').show();
            if (whichcat == 'maincat') {
                var replacevar = 1; 

            } else {
                var getcat = whichcat.split("|");
                var replacevar = parseInt(getcat[1]) + 1;


            }
                $( '#prod').hide();
                document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = '';
                for (i = replacevar; i <=5; i++) {
                    $( '#cat'+i ).hide();
                    document.getElementById('scat|'+i).innerHTML = '';
                }


                $.post(url, {'submit': true, 'pcat':catid, cache: true, prod : ''}, function(response) {                    
                    if(response) {
                        response = response.trim()
                        if (response == 'no') {
                            /*$.post(url, {'submit': true, 'pcat':catid, cache: true, prod = 'yes'}, function(response) {
                                $( '#prod').show();
                                document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = response;
                            });*/
                            getprodcuts(catid);

                        } else {
                            $( '#cat'+replacevar ).show();
                            document.getElementById('scat|'+replacevar).innerHTML = response;
                        }   
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Please try later');                      
                    }
               });
          });


    });

    </script>


    <script>
            $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
             var me = $(this); 
            $( "#ajaxloadingimg",me).show();

            });
            $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
            var me = $(this); 
           $( "#ajaxloadingimg",me).hide();
            });

        </script> 

            <div id="cat2" style="display:none">
                <label>Sub Category</label><select name="scat2" id="scat|2" class="catclass">
                </select><div id="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">loading...</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cat3" style="display:none">
                <label>Sub Category</label><select name="scat3" id="scat|3" class="catclass">
                </select><div id="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">loading...</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cat4" style="display:none">
                <label>Sub Category</label><select name="scat4" id="scat|4" class="catclass">
                </select><div id="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">loading...</div>
            </div>
            <div id="cat5" style="display:none">
                <label>Sub Category</label><select name="scat5" id="scat|5" class="catclass">
                </select><div id="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">loading...</div>
            </div>
            <div id="prod" style="display:none">
                <label style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:8px;" >Product</label><select name="products[]" id="products" multiple="multiple" >
                </select>
            </div>
```

=> Loading not showing for all in ajax request instead it only showing for first element. Please help me. thanks in advance.
 Loading not showing for all in ajax request instead it only showing for first element. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: <script>
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
   var me = $(this);    
   $( "#ajaxloadingimg",me).show();

    });
    $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
     var me = $(this);    
   $( "#ajaxloadingimg",me).hide();
    });

</script>

Comment: but working above code too...

Comment: I think the question is not really clear. The answers are correct as far as what was asked, but what is really required is that when a `select` is changed, some sort of ajax request is kicked off and a loading panel (possibly specific to the select) should show.

Answer (score 1):

ID is a unique identifier inside a page.

There should never be two elements that have the same id. Try changing that for a class, and use `.ajaxloadingimg`

Change :

```
<div id="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">
```

To :

```
<div class="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: yes it is correct but now displaying all the <div class="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;">

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: i'm using the dependent selectbox in that data is loading trough the ajax working fine. but problem is that while ajax call i want show the ajax loading img by side the selectbox till load another dependent selectbox.

Comment: You'll need to catch event more specific than `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` for that.

Comment: @Mindlance in that case you should add the code to the question which does loading the data in ajax.

Comment: @Mindlance No one will do your code for you. We've gived you some clues and answered the original question, if that's not enough for you, feel free to ask another more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `id="ajaxloadingimg"` with `class="ajaxloadingimg"` and correspondingly in your javascript do this:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
   $( ".ajaxloadingimg").show();

});
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
 $( ".ajaxloadingimg").hide();
});
```

The whole purpose of `id` is to uniquely identify an element. So you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. In that case we use the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have same id defined for multiple elements.

`ajaxloadingimg` is used for divs. Instead of using it as Id you should use Class.

```
<div class="ajaxloadingimg" style="display:none;"> should be the proper one.
```